# Removing recursion in Yaroslavskiys Dual Pivot Quicksort

Tags: c, recursion, qsort

I started working on a modified version of Yaroslavskiys Dual Pivot Quicksort and as a first step I tried removing recursion (The code is based on the recursive version in this [paper](http://codeblab.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/DualPivotQuicksort.pdf)). This seems to be a little old-fashioned maybe but I still would like to give it a try. Here is the C-Code I have so far. Its working as intended, but I am a little concerned about pathological cases where local stack might overflow:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define QS_STACK_SIZE     96
#define QS_ARR_SIZE       10000000

#define INT_SWAP(x_,y_)\
do {\
    int tmp_ = (x_);\
    (x_) = (y_);\
    (y_) = tmp_;\
} while(0)

void qsort_yaro(int *a, int left, int right, int div);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    static int a[QS_ARR_SIZE];

    srand (time (NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < QS_ARR_SIZE; i ++)
        a[i] = rand();

    printf ("Sorting %i elements ...\n", QS_ARR_SIZE);
    qsort_yaro (a, 0, QS_ARR_SIZE - 1, 3);

    for (i = 0; i < QS_ARR_SIZE - 1; i ++)
        if (a[i] > a[i + 1])
            {
            printf ("ERROR : Sequence not ascending!\n");
            break;
            }

    if (i == QS_ARR_SIZE - 1)
        printf ("OK : Sequence ascending!\n");

    return 0;
}

void qsort_yaro(int *a, int left, int right, int div)
{
    int i, j, k, third;
    int len;
    int m1, m2;
    int pivot1, pivot2;
    int less, great;
    int dist;
    int hi[QS_STACK_SIZE];
    int lo[QS_STACK_SIZE];
    int lvl = -1;
    int max_stack = 0;

    lo[++lvl] = left;
    hi[lvl] = right;

    while (lvl >= 0)
        {
        left = lo[lvl];
        right = hi[lvl--];

        while ((len = right - left) >= 27)
            { // insertion sort for tiny array
            third = len / div;
            //
            // "medians"
            m1 = left + third;
            m2 = right - third;

            if (m1 <= left)
                m1 = left + 1;
            if (m2 >= right)
                m2 = right - 1;
            if (a[m1] < a[m2])
                {
                INT_SWAP(a[m1], a[left]);
                INT_SWAP(a[m2], a[right]);
                }
            else
                {
                INT_SWAP(a[m1], a[right]);
                INT_SWAP(a[m2], a[left]);
                }

            // pivots
            pivot1 = a[left];
            pivot2 = a[right];
            // pointers
            less = left + 1;
            great = right - 1;
            // sorting
            for (k = less; k <= great; k++)
                {
                if (a[k] < pivot1)
                    {
                    INT_SWAP(a[k], a[less]);
                    less++;
                    }
                else if (a[k] > pivot2)
                    {
                    while (k < great && a[great] > pivot2)
                        great--;
                    INT_SWAP(a[k], a[great]);
                    great--;
                    if (a[k] < pivot1)
                        {
                        INT_SWAP(a[k], a[less]);
                        less++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            // swaps
            dist = great - less;
            if (dist < 13)
                div++;

            INT_SWAP(a[less - 1], a[left]);
            INT_SWAP(a[great + 1], a[right]);

//            lo[++lvl] = left;
//            hi[lvl]   = less - 2;
//            lo[++lvl] = great + 2;
//            hi[lvl]   = right;

            // Push the smaller interval on top for less stack usage
            // subarrays
            if (less - 2 - left > right - great - 2)
                {
                lo[++lvl] = left;
                hi[lvl]   = less - 2;
                lo[++lvl] = great + 2;
                hi[lvl]   = right;
                }
            else
                {
                lo[++lvl] = great + 2;
                hi[lvl]   = right;
                lo[++lvl] = left;
                hi[lvl]   = less - 2;
                }
            if (max_stack < lvl)
                max_stack = lvl;
            // equal elements
            if (dist > len - 13 && pivot1 != pivot2)
                {
                for (k = less; k <= great; k++)
                    {
                    if (a[k] == pivot1)
                        {
                        INT_SWAP(a[k], a[less]);
                        less++;
                        }
                    else if (a[k] == pivot2)
                        {
                        INT_SWAP(a[k], a[great]);
                        great--;
                        if (a[k] == pivot1)
                            {
                            INT_SWAP(a[k], a[less]);
                            less++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            // subarray
            if (pivot1 < pivot2)
                {
                left  = less;
                right = great;
                }
            else
                {
                left  = lo[lvl];
                right = hi[lvl--];
                }
            }

        for (i = left + 1; i <= right; i++)
            for (j = i; j > left && a[j] < a[j - 1]; j--)
                INT_SWAP (a[j], a[j - 1]);
        }
    printf ("Max Stack Size : %i\n", max_stack);
}
```

I tweaked the original Implementation by this little change

```
        if (less - 2 - left > right - great - 2)
            {
            lo[++lvl] = left;
            hi[lvl]   = less - 2;
            lo[++lvl] = great + 2;
            hi[lvl]   = right;
            }
        else
            {
            lo[++lvl] = great + 2;
            hi[lvl]   = right;
            lo[++lvl] = left;
            hi[lvl]   = less - 2;
            }
```

which is based on the same idea as in the conventional iterative 1-pivot implementation where larger parts are pushed to the stack in order to limit stack size to log(n). Here, the smaller part is put on top of the stack, in order to pop it back as early as possible.

I did a few experiments with randomly generated arrays of 10.000.000 elements and could actually save up to 5 stack levels by this method (with a maximum of ~45).

Now, I dont find a rigorous argument why stack size should be limited by a constant in this implementation, so either I oversaw the math here, or I need a better idea and implementation.

Comment: Not sure O(1) stack (or equivalent) is ever going to be enough.  However, quicksort can be implemented to require O(log n) stack size (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Space_complexity).

Comment: Oh, unless of course you have a maximum input size!  Then it's indeed possible to bound the recursion depth to log(max input size).

Comment: Input size will be bounded only by MAX_INT32 and it is clear that one can implement 1-pivot qsort with log(n) stack size. But here, I dont see why it could not happen that the left and right part of the 3-way partion stay very small and the middle part being huge, this would push a lot to the stack and the tweak does not prevent that.